# Trouble getting bathroom fan/light working

Tags: electrical

[image][image]

I know this is wired correctly, the outlet has power but yet the light won't turn on nor will the fan... Any thoughts?

Comment: What outlet????

Comment: How are you telling that the outlet has power?

Comment: I used a voltage detector.  Am I missing something?  I meant switch sorry... late night

Comment: the wire are all tight including the neutral

Comment: Just because the neutral wire is tight under the wire nut doesn't mean you have a neutral present.

Comment: Paul can you elaborate?  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have a loose neutral.

Comment: Ditto!! Same thought.